# How to use enum passed to dll as method parameter?

Tags: c#, dll, enums

Enum in my main application:

```
enum variable
{
    NULL,
    low,
    high
}
```

Main function in my dll:

```
class MainClass
{
    Enum variable;

    public static string Start(Enum variable)
    {
        variable = variable;
    }
}
```

And now I want to create a struct in another file in my dll with field of variable type but I get an error:
"The type or namespace name 'variable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
What can I do about it?

```
struct NewStruct
{
    string word;
    variable v;
}
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the assembly containing the enums definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. (but only for test.. it is crepy code :D)

```
class MainClass
{
    variable myenum; //Not Enum

    public static string Start(variable tmpval)
    {
        myenum = tmpval;

        return string.Empty; //this method needs a return value
    }
}
```

I hope this isn't productive code..